# Future Builder is returning Null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

FutureBuilder is returning null even though I am able to get the data from the 
Json.

This is the function that I had given in the future of the FutureBuilder

```
Future<Map> setVarsHome() async {
      resultJson = await requestHomeAPI(context);
      print("RESULTJSON");
      print(resultJson);
      return resultJson;
    }
```

This is the FutureBuilder Widget

```
FutureBuilder<Map>(
                future: setVarsHome(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  print("This is snapshot : ${snapshot.data}");
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    homeItems = HomeGrid.fromJson(snapshot.data).data.items;
                    if (snapshot.data != null) {
                      return GridView.count(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 7.0, vertical: 10.0),
                        crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
                        childAspectRatio: 0.545,
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        primary: false,
                        children: List.generate(
                          /// Get data in flashSaleItem.dart (ListItem folder)
                          homeItems.length,
                          (index) => ItemGrid(homeItems[index]),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.data == null) {
                      return _imageLoading(context);
                    }
                  } else {
                    return _imageLoading(context);
                  }
                })
```